# How to perform wilcox test on the result of train () function

Tags: r, r-caret, statistical-test

I have the following code in R and I want to perform a statistical test (wilcox) to determine if there is a significance difference between the two models.

```
set.seed(308)

rand_search <- train(
    Effort ~ ., data = d,
    method = "svmRadial",
    ##Create 20 random parameter values
    tuneLength = 20,
    metric = "RMSE",
    preProc = c("center", "scale"),
    trControl = rand_ctrl
) 
  model1 <- predict(rand_search, newdata = test1)

And another search algorithm like grid
grid_search <- train(
    Effort ~ ., data = d,
    method = "svmRadial",
    ##Create 20 random parameter values
    tuneLength = 20,
    metric = "RMSE",
    preProc = c("center", "scale"),
    trControl = rand_ctrl
) 
model2 <- predict(grid_search, newdata = test1)
```

My question is what is the next step so that we perform the wilcox test such as
wilcox.test (model1, model2)

Comment: I think you are correct, just you can use `wilcox.test (model1, model2)`  and check the p-value. Whether the p-value is significant or not.

Comment: @BappaDas Yes, p-value was significant, I just want to confirm that is this the right way to perform wilcoxon test after train function? 
someone suggested to use '''wilcox.test(model1$coef, model2$coef)''' instead of the above mentioned way.

Comment: significance testing should be done on the performance metric from re-sampling or `wilcox.test(model1$resample$Accuracy, model2$resample$Accuracy)` in case of a classifier with accuracy measure

Comment: @missuse I am using RMSE because data is regression based. wilcox.test(model1$resample$RMSE, model2$resample$RMSE)
so it should be like this then?

Comment: Yes Tanveer Jan.